# AEM: URL Shortening

Tags: aem, sling

We have a multi lingual website with the structure like `/content/<app>/<language>/login-page` , I am looking to get rid of `/content/<app>/<language>`and the .html from the URLs, so that instead of accessing pages like `http://www.application.com/content/<app>/en/login-page.html` or `http://www.application.es/content/<app>/en/login-page.html` I can access the page like `http://www.application.com/login-page` and `http://www.application.es/login-page`. As far as I know this has to be taken care of using Sling Mappings and Rewrite Rules in Apache. But not exactly sure how to achieve that. What the mappings will  be in both apache and the Sling Mappings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent write up on this here :

http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/cq/multidomain-cq-mappings-and-apache-configuration#.VP-psmSUc44

Since you have two domains , you will need two mappings in **etc/map**. Something like this :

```
{
   jcr: primaryType: "sling:OrderedFolder",
    www.application_com: {
     sling:internalRedirect: ["/content/application/en.html"],                               
     jcr:primaryType: "sling:Mapping",
     sling:match: "www.application.com/$"
    },
    www.application.com: {
      sling:internalRedirect: ["/content/application/en"],         
      jcr:primaryType: "sling:Mapping",
      redirect: {
         sling:internalRedirect: ["/content/application/en/$1","/$1"],
         jcr:primaryType: "sling:Mapping",
         sling:match: "(.+)$"
       }
    },
    www.application_es: {
     sling:internalRedirect: ["/content/application/es.html"],                               
     jcr:primaryType: "sling:Mapping",
     sling:match: "application.com/$"
    },
    www.application.es: {
      sling:internalRedirect: ["/content/application/es"],         
      jcr:primaryType: "sling:Mapping",
      redirect: {
         sling:internalRedirect: ["/content/application/es/$1","/$1"],
         jcr:primaryType: "sling:Mapping",
         sling:match: "(.+)$"
       }
    },
}
```

Rewrite rules for .com in web server :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.application.com

        DocumentRoot /opt/cq/dispatcher/publish
        <Directory /opt/cq/dispatcher/publish>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
            SetHandler dispatcher-handler
        </IfModule>
        RewriteEngine On
           RewriteRule ^/$ /content/application/en.html [PT,L]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bin
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/libs
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tmp
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/var
           RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /content/application/en/$1 [PT,L]
    </VirtualHost>
```

Rewrite rules for .es in web server :

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.application.es

        DocumentRoot /opt/cq/dispatcher/publish
        <Directory /opt/cq/dispatcher/publish>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
            SetHandler dispatcher-handler
        </IfModule>
        RewriteEngine On
           RewriteRule ^/$ /content/application/es.html [PT,L]
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/apps
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bin
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/content
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/libs
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tmp
           RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/var
           RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /content/application/es/$1 [PT,L]
    </VirtualHost>
```

[All rules have been adapted from the link mentioned above]

Extensionless url's don't work in Sling  , so you will have to re write url's from webserver to add them and then
    write linktransformer in aem to remove them form the links in the html , here's a link to a post that explains this
    http://www.citytechinc.com/us/en/blog/2013/04/extensionless-urls-in-adobe-experience-manager.html

Comment: Thanks Sharath. I got one question. What is the difference between shortening the URLs and using vanity URLs. I mean won't I just use vanity URL and avoid all the effort.

Comment: vanity urls are meant to be used in special circumstances. For example  there is a page that has list of products with discounts and you want to send out a mailer with a catchy url like example.com/flat50 . They have to be unique throughout the server. So without mapping for .com and .es /flat50 would fail. All url's having vanity path could have performance impact (as every request would have to be checked against a huge list. disclaimer : this conclusion is based on my understanding of how it works , i could be wrong )

Comment: check this link : http://apache-sling.73963.n3.nabble.com/URL-mapping-and-vanity-URLs-td4021126.html .

Comment: Also note that vanity URLs can be either an internal redirect or an external 302 redirect. With sling:Mapping you can set the status code to 300, 301, 302, 303 or 307.